# Read CSV with linebreaks in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

Read CSV with linebreaks in pyspark
I want to read with pyspark a "legal" (it follows [RFC4180](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfA5F.png)) CSV that has breaklines (CRLF) in some of the rows. The next code sample shows how it does seem when opened it with Notepad++:

[image]

I try to read it with ***sqlCtx.read.load*** using **format ='com.databricks.spark.csv.** and the resulting dataset shows two rows instead of one in these specific cases. I am using Spark 2.1.0.2 version.

Is there any command or alternative way of reading the csv that allows me to read these two lines only as one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "csv" instead of Databricks CSV - the last one redirects now to default Spark reader. But, it's only a hint :)

In Spark 2.2 there was added new option - `wholeFile`. If  you write this:

```
spark.read.option("wholeFile", "true").csv("file.csv")
```

it will read all file and handle multiline CSV.

There is no such option in Spark 2.1. You can read file using `sparkContext.wholeTextFile` or just use newer verison

Comment: I think this solution is only useful when you just have two lines and you want to merge them into one. But what if you have 100 lines, and the problem is in the 50th line? Then only lines 50th and 51st need to be fixed so at the end we should have 99 lines .

Comment: @daloman I don't understand. Spark will automatically recognize which lines should be merged

Comment: As I understood reading the documentation, this options returns the whole file as one row. So, it collapses all lines in one.

Comment: @daloman SparkContext.wholeFile - yes. That's why you must manually parse it. In Spark 2.2 there is option in DataFrameReader, there will be normal rows, not one file as string

Answer (score 2):

wholeFile does not exist (anymore?) in the spark api documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

This solution will work:

```
spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").csv("file.csv")
```

From the api documentation:

*multiLine – parse records, which may span multiple lines. If None is set, it uses the default value, false*